# Rails Routing Different Show Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an academy controller that has and index and a show.

The index shows the courses and the show displays the categories in the course. I want to add a show_episodes method to the controller that will be called in a show_episodes.html.erb that will show the episodes related to that course and that category.

I have the query written and everything but when it comes to routing what would be the best way to route so the path in the url is academy(index)/course_id(shows sections in the course)/category_id(shows the episodes in the each section)
this is what my routes look like

```
resources :academy, :only => %w(index show)
```

my controller

```
class AcademyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_users_user!

  def index
    @courses = Course.active
                        .select("sum(progress)/count(1) AS progress, courses.name, courses.id, courses.course_episodes_count")
                    .joins("left outer join course_categories on course_categories.course_id = courses.id")
                    .joins("left outer join course_episodes on course_episodes.course_category_id = course_categories.id")
                    .joins("left outer join user_course_progresses on course_episodes.id = user_course_progresses.course_episode_id")
                    .group("courses.name, courses.id, courses.course_episodes_count")

  end

  def show

    @course_categories = CourseCategory.active
                                       .select("sum(progress)/count(1) AS progress, course_categories.order, course_categories.name, course_categories.id, course_episodes_count, img_url")
                                       .joins("left outer join course_episodes on course_categories.id = course_episodes.course_category_id")
                                       .joins("left outer join user_course_progresses on course_episodes.id = user_course_progresses.course_episode_id")
                                       .group("course_categories.order, course_categories.name, course_categories.id, course_episodes_count, img_url")
                                       .order(order: :asc)   


  end

  def show_episodes
    course_category_id = params[:id]

    @course_episodes = CourseEpisode.active
                                    .select("p.progress, course_episodes.*")
                                    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_course_progresses p on p.course_episode_id = course_episodes.id")
                                          .where("course_categories_id = ? and p.user_id = ? and p.course_episode_id = course_episodes.id", course_category_id, current_users_user.id) 
                                    .order(order: :asc)

    @course_categories = CourseCategory.active
                                       .select("name, courses_id")
                                       .where("id = ? ", course_category_id)
                                       .first       

  end

end
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
resources :academy do
    get 'show_episodes', on: :member
end
```

will generate a route like:

`/academy/:academy_id/show_episodes`

that will call the `show_episodes` method on your controller.

Comment: thanks for the reply. In my html file can i add a link to like this?               
      <%= link_to show_episodes_academy, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> View Episodes
        <% end %>

Comment: run `rake routes` on your console in order to get the correct route, but yes, `show_episodes_academy_path(@academy)` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Another way....

```
Resources :academy do
  member do
    get :show_episodes
  end
end
```